# Simple Dropdown List PHP code from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a simple dropdown list on a table, however, my codes don't seem to be working, I was wondering if there any issue with the way I connect and retrieve? or its just my codes for the dropdown list is wrong. Here are the codes for it, below screenshot contains my database along with the place I want to put my dropdown list. Thanks for the time.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("Select sbranch_name from branches");
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sbranch_name);

//while ($stmt->fetch())
//{
//    $stmt .="<option>". $row['sbranch_name']. "</option>";
    //echo '<input type="checkbox" name="sbranch_name[]" value="'.$sbranch_name.'". <br>';
//  echo $stmt;
//}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<select name='sbranch_name'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "'>" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}   
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

[image: [Screenshot of database]]

[image: [Dropdown List]]

Comment: `bind_result` call shouldn't be there

Comment: @peter alright so i remove that line, anything else to remove as well?

Comment: Before `$result->num_rows`, add `print_r($result->fetch_all())` to dump all the records in the database table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

using `mysqli->query`

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$sql="Select sbranch_name from branches";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
//$stmt->bind_result($sbranch_name);

//while ($stmt->fetch())
//{
//    $stmt .="<option>". $row['sbranch_name']. "</option>";
    //echo '<input type="checkbox" name="sbranch_name[]" value="'.$sbranch_name.'". <br>';
//  echo $stmt;
//}
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<select name='sbranch_name'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "'>" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}   
//$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in when you binding query, why dont you use below code.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("Select sbranch_name from branches");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "<select name='images'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "'>" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```